# Put an Asterisk SIP call on hold via AMI

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I'm attempting to put a call on hold via the Asterisk Management Interface (AMI), and I've worked out that in order to do this you need to effectively park the call. Where I'm running into trouble is the second channel in which you are placing into and parking.

I tried putting the Channel2 has extension 702, but that doesn't work as it complains that it isn't a channel (obviously). So how do I create the second channel? Do I originate another call?

My features.conf detailing parkedcalls:

```ini
[general]
parkext => 700          
parkpos => 701-720      
                
                
context => parkedcalls      
;parkinghints = no      
;parkingtime => 45
```

I'm using the PAMI libary (AMI for PHP):

```php
$parkMsg = new ParkAction($_REQUEST['channel'],'702');//Getting channel is the original call chan, 702 is my misguided attempt at parking
$results = $pamiClient->send($parkMsg);
```

Comment: Post relevant parts of your conf file.

Comment: I'm doing this via AMI, so just post up the [general] in features where parked details are?

Comment: Is there code that you post ?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using [PAMI](http://marcelog.github.io/PAMI/php-doc/html/db_Message_Action_ParkAction.html), you might want to mention that in your question.

You probably want to look at the documention for the AMI command you're using, which is [here](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/ManagerAction_Park).

The channel2 is the channel to announce the parking space to, and to send the Parked call to if it times out. It needs to be another live channel.

Here's the asterisk help on this command for reference:

```
CLI> manager show command Park
Action: Park
Synopsis: Park a channel
Privilege: call,all
Description: Park a channel.
Variables: (Names marked with * are required)
    *Channel: Channel name to park
    *Channel2: Channel to announce park info to (and return to if timeout)
    Timeout: Number of milliseconds to wait before callback.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, the solution is much simpler than I had thought.

To do it, you Park with Channel1 and Channel2 set as the same thing.

Example:

```
Action: Park
Channel: SIP/1037-0000bb4a
Channel2: SIP/1037-0000bb4a
```

Not sure if it's correct, but it works well enough (it puts the caller on hold)

Comment: Channel2 comes into play when the Timeout happens. Set the timeout to something low and watch what happens.

Comment: That's fair enough, how would I.put that customer on hold then?

Comment: I don't understand your question. But what you want to do is set Channel2: to a dial string so that it will call back the person who put them on hold after the timeout elapses, or else set the timeout really high so that it never times out.

Comment: When I initially tried  dial string (that was the first thing I did) it said it was not a valid channel (I used SIP/1037)

Comment: Looks like I was wrong about that, Channel2: does need to be another live channel. It announces the Parking space to Channel2: in addition to calling it back if the timeout is reached.